# Sizing SVG in HTML table cell

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a HTML table with an inline SVG spanning all rows. By default, the SVG takes all the available width. How can I achieve the following behavior?

- The height of the table should be computed as if the SVG wasn’t present.
- The SVG should take all the available vertical space, preserving aspect ratio.
- The rest of the table should be laid out as usual.

See [my own answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56554978/6366251) for a rough approximation of how it should look like.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="svg-cell" rowspan="4">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 40">
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" />
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Kaiido I deliberately set no size on the SVG because it should fill all vertical space in the table (however without increasing the size of the table). I that’s not clear from the question, I’d be happy to improve it.

Comment: @Kaiido That’s just an example. The width could be different from the height.

Comment: I just changed the viewBox to not be square, to avoid possible future confusion.

Comment: It was not creating confusion, what is confusing is what you are willing to achieve. The square was good to explain things easily but anyway... Here with your 1/2 ratio image, if the table is 100px height, you want to get your svg rendered with 50px width?

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Kaiido Let’s put in that way: the fact that it was a square was confusing me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution would be to hide the SVG temporarily and set it’s size with JavaScript. I’m ignoring questions like padding and margin, but it should give you an idea how the end result should look like.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("svg").style.height = document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].clientHeight + "px";
  document.getElementById("svg").style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
#svg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td id="svg-cell" rowspan="4">
      <svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 40">
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" />
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```